Failure to Generate iOS React Native 0.72.12 Project in Custom Directory
If the project structure follows the one below, running pod install is successful:
└── guideProgram 
    ├── package.json 
    ├── node_modules 
    └── ios 
        └── Podfile

However, when the structure is customized as follows:
└── myProgram 
    ├── rn
    ├   ├── node_modules 
    ├   └── package.json 
    └─ ios
       └── Podfile

It results in an error message:
"[!] Invalid Podfile file: undefined method `prepare_react_native_project!' for #Pod::Podfile:0x00007f8733259588."
It has been bothering me for several days now！Any help will be appreaciated
